# React/Redux. Which library or component choose for localization, internationalization?

Tags: reactjs, localization, internationalization, redux, translation

I would like to

- translate constant
- translate router ways (site.com/%lang%/page)
- translate logic (date, currency, users gender)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[React Intl. - Internationalize React apps.](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl)

[Redux binding for React Intl.](https://github.com/ratson/react-intl-redux)